# Column Name also appear as a row when querying the external table for specific column

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, polybase, sql-data-warehouse

I have a file in azure data lake store.  I am using polybase to move data from data lake store to data warehouse.
I followed all the steps which are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store).

Let's say I have created external table as External_Emp which has 3 columns : ID, Name, Dept.

When I am running following query:

```
select * from External_Emp;
```

Then, it is showing me all the records which is right.
But when i am selecting a specific column/columns then it shows the column name in a row. For Ex., if i run following query:

```
select Name from External_Emp;
```

Then output is :

```
Name
-----
Name
1
2
3
```

whereas, the output should be:

```
Name
------
1
2
3
```

Similarly , when i run query:

```
select ID, Name from External_Emp;
```

Then it shows following output:

```
ID | Name
---------
ID | Name
1  | abc
2  | xyz
3  | pqr
```

whereas, the output should be :

```
ID | Name
--------
1  | abc
2  | pqr
3  | xyz
```

why is it showing the column names in the separate row?
Is that a bug?

I checked the data in csv file in azure data lake multiple times. It doesn't have repetitive column names.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the External Table and the External File Format. Then recreate the External File Format with `FIRST_ROW=2` which will skip one row as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?&view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=delimited):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT TextFileFormat
WITH
(   FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT
,    FORMAT_OPTIONS    (   FIELD_TERMINATOR = '|'
                    ,    STRING_DELIMITER = ''
                    ,    DATE_FORMAT         = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'
                    ,    USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE
                    ,    FIRST_ROW = 2
                    )
);
```